# JavaFx installaion returns Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while: 15/15

Tags: javafx

I am using 
Windows 7 Ultimate edition
Java 10.0.2
Eclipse OXYGEN.3A (April 2018) Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

When I try to install the JavaFx from the location http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/1.2.0/site/

then I got the following

```
Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while: 15/15

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE - PDE 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.201501301049)
  Missing requirement: JDT UI Tooling for JavaFX 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui 1.2.0.201501301049) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib 2.7.1' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.201501301049)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui [1.2.0.201501301049]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - PDE 1.2.0.201501301049 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.pde.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.201501301049)
    To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
```

What requirement am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

You do unterstand, that the version of e(fx)clipse you're attempting to install is basically years old!

For example check [here](http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/) - the [updates-released](http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/) section shows versions up to **3.3.0** with a fairly recent date *feature_3.3.0.201805280700*.

So either use this or use the [marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse) (which seem to point to version **3.0.0**) - drag and drop the install button into your running Eclipse instance or use the marketplace from within Eclipse itself (Help menu, as far as I recall or installable) and search for ***efxclipse***.

Comment: Thank you very much dzim. I have changed my installation of eclipse from April 2018 to March 2018 and I have successfully installed it using the option marketplace entry.

Comment: The idea came basically from the plugins author, Tom Schindl, I was just quicker then him...  Please accept the answer as correct (you can set the tick) and, if you want, up-vote the answer.